# Jmeter websocket: cannot connect to remote server

Tags: websocket, jmeter

I use Jmeter websocket sample to do the load test, but i always failed to conect to the remote server. Is there any one can give me a hand? Thank you very much!

[image: Jmeter websocket sample config]

Here is the logs:

Thread Name: Thread Group 1-1

Sample Start: 2018-07-24 10:40:17 CST

Load time: 30012

Connect Time: 0

Latency: 0

Size in bytes: 0

Sent bytes:0

Headers size in bytes: 0

Body size in bytes: 0

Sample Count: 1

Error Count: 0

Data type ("text"|"bin"|""):

Response code: 200

Response message:

[Execution Flow]

- Opening new connection
- Using response message pattern ""
- Using disconnect pattern ""
- Waiting for the server connection for 10000 MILLISECONDS
- Cannot connect to the remote server
- Waiting for messages for 20000 MILLISECONDS
- Leaving streaming connection open

[Variables]

- Message count: 0

[Problems]

Response headers:

SampleResult fields:

ContentType:

DataEncoding: UTF-8

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Check that you can reach port `8083` of the `10.10.56.66` host from the machine where JMeter is running using [telnet client](https://www.lifewire.com/what-is-telnet-2626026) or equivalent as the messages you're getting might indicate that the server is down or its firewall doesn't allow inbound connections to port `8083`
2. Double check your requirements, it might be the case you need to use `wss` protocol in case of secure websocket connections. As per [About HTML5 WebSocket article](https://www.websocket.org/aboutwebsocket.html):

   > Note that a ws:// and wss:// prefix are proposed to indicate a WebSocket and a secure WebSocket connection, respectively.
3. Check out the URL which is known to work, i.e. `ws://echo.websocket.org` on port `80` or `wss://echo.websocket.org` on port `443` - the service basically replies with the message it receives. See https://www.websocket.org/echo.html for browser version
4. Check *jmeter.log* file for any suspicious entries, it might be the case of incorrect installation, i.e. missing dependency library
5. Be aware that there is an alternative set of plugins: [JMeter WebSocket Samplers by Peter Doornbosch](https://bitbucket.org/pjtr/jmeter-websocket-samplers) which seem to be more advanced than the plugin you're using which was last updated 3 years ago. See [JMeter WebSocket Samplers - A Practical Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-websocket-samplers-a-practical-guide) article for more information if needed.

Comment: I got a hint from the method in Article 5, we used the latest websocket to solve the problem. Thanks very much.